# Deserialization with System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1 results in null property values

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I have the following json:

```
{
 "GameConfig":{
  "TeamConstraint":{
     "SameTeamPlayers":[
        "Raghav",
        "Surya"
     ],
     "OppositeTeamPlayers":[
        "Wolfman",
        "Pawan"
     ]
  },
  "Players":[
     "Tramp",
     "Surya",
     "Raghav",
     "Krishna",
     "Sanjay",
     "Bala",
     "Wolfman",
     "Eagle",
     "Sai",
     "Pawan",
     "Joo",
     "Srikanth"
  ],
  "Ranks":{
     "Tramp":10,
     "Surya":10,
     "Raghav":8,
     "Krishna":8,
     "Eagle":8,
     "Sai":8,
     "Sanjay":7.5,
     "Pawan":5,
     "Wolfman":5.0,
     "Srikanth":6,
     "Bala":4.5,
     "Joo":1.5
   }
  }
}
```

I am writing a simple console app .NET Core 3.1. I have tried both the JSON.NET as well as the new MSFT System.Text.Json deserializer. But I get only null values for all of the properties with the following Model object.

```
[Serializable]
public class GameConfig
{
    public TeamConstraint TeamConstraint { get; set; }
    
    public List<string> Players { get; set; }
    
    public Dictionary<string, double> Ranks { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TeamConstraint
{
    public List<string> OppositeTeamPlayers { get; set; }

    public List<string> SameTeamPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried several additional options like using a contract resolver with CamelCase properties and changing the code and json accordingly but nothing has worked so far. What am I missing?

This is the code I am using to deserialize.

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(TeamGeneratorStandardSettings.Default.GameConfigFile);
var gameConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameConfig>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Obviously you are using wrong model for given json

Comment: Can you share the code which does the deserialization? I think you need to create one more class with property `public GameConfig GameConfig{get;set:}` and deserialize to that's class object

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Added the deserialization code

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=NtYLU6bwMBZA8OafHA6H

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize into `GameConfig`, whereas that is simply a top-level property of your overall json object structure.  You need a new top-level type to deserialize into that contains your `GameConfig` object.

```
public class GameData
{
    public GameConfig GameConfig { get; set; } 
}

var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(TeamGeneratorStandardSettings.Default.GameConfigFile);
var gameConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameData>(jsonString);
```

Alternatively, you could remove the wrapping object from your json and still deserialize directly to a `GameConfig` object:

```json
{
  "TeamConstraint":{
     "SameTeamPlayers":[
        "Raghav",
        "Surya"
     ],
     "OppositeTeamPlayers":[
        "Wolfman",
        "Pawan"
     ]
  },
  "Players":[
     "Tramp",
     "Surya",
     "Raghav",
     "Krishna",
     "Sanjay",
     "Bala",
     "Wolfman",
     "Eagle",
     "Sai",
     "Pawan",
     "Joo",
     "Srikanth"
  ],
  "Ranks":{
     "Tramp":10,
     "Surya":10,
     "Raghav":8,
     "Krishna":8,
     "Eagle":8,
     "Sai":8,
     "Sanjay":7.5,
     "Pawan":5,
     "Wolfman":5.0,
     "Srikanth":6,
     "Bala":4.5,
     "Joo":1.5
   }
  }
```

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(TeamGeneratorStandardSettings.Default.GameConfigFile);
var gameConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameConfig>(jsonString);
```